# Exclude folder in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

How can I exclude my `X` folder from the build?

If I remove it manually and `dotnet build` and `dotnet run` it takes along the lines of 20 seconds to run both commands and get me a working server.

On the other hand if I include it manually it takes something like 2 minutes to run both commands.

I've tried adding:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="X\**" />
    <Compile Remove="wwwroot\**" />
    <Content Remove="X\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="X\**" />
    <None Remove="X\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to my `.csproj` file, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

So how can I instruct `dotnet` to ignore that folder completely?

Comment: isn't common practice to just exclude the `node_modules` from source control (generally in the .gitignore)?

Comment: a `node_modules` folder at the root of the project folder should already be excluded, is this project really using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK? (csproj file)

Comment: @Jonesopolis That only exclude it from being versioned using `git`. When you compile your source code, being it locally or on a virtual machine or a docker container, the problem of `dotnet` recursively trying to parse and compile stuff in that directory remains.

Comment: @MartinUllrich I've committed a horrible newbie mistake. I didn't know about that exception. I've used `node_modules` as the most common example I could imagine. I've edited the question to reflect a more generic folder `X` (in my case it's not not `node_modules`).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To exclude large folders to speed up the build, the items need to be excluded from the "default" items (the pattern searched by default) since the most time is spent searching the folder (though MSBuild 15.5 will contain optimisations for that).

Add this to the project file to exclude large folders that should never be searched in the first place:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);my_large_folder\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Yes, that fixes it. Thanks. For future visitors: the lines I've put in the question have pretty much no effect, so you might as well remove them.